# Mixing tasks and graphicx packages

Tags: graphics, tasks

I'm trying to setup what you can see in the following image, essentially an image side by side with a tasks environment. The image could be inside or outside the tasks environment, I don't care as long as it works.

[image]

(I edited this image with MSPaint)

I've been using tasks throughout my document and I would prefer not to change this package.

In this next code I'm posting a few of my attempts to replicate my target, they've all failed in one way or another as it's explained in the code.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1.1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

%\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tasks} 
    \settasks{style=enumerate,label-width=1.5em,label-offset=0.5em,item-indent=2em,label-align=right,resume=true,after-item-skip=0pt}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

%tasks only
%Doesn't work, looks almost right but images are not shown the preferred way. Code is a bit dirty too.
\begin{tasks}[resume=false](4)
\task*(2) \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dummy}
\task[] Equations
\task[] $P=(0,2)$
\task*(2)[] \task*(2)[] $a:\, y=x$
\task*(2)[] \task*(2)[] $b:\, y=x+2$
\task*(2)[] \task*(2)[] $c:\, y=-x+2$
\task*(2) \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dummy}
\task[] Equations
\task[] $P=(0,2)$
\task*(2)[] \task*(2)[] $a:\, y=x$
\task*(2)[] \task*(2)[] $b:\, y=x+2$
\task*(2)[] \task*(2)[] $c:\, y=-x+2$
\end{tasks}

\newpage

%several tasks inside several multicols
%Doesn't work, numbers should go on the left, it also means each example needs its own tasks and a multicols environment.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dummy}
\columnbreak
\begin{tasks}[resume=false](2)
\task Equations
\task[] $P=(0,2)$
\task![] $a:\, y=x$
\task![] $b:\, y=x+2$
\task![] $c:\, y=-x+2$
\end{tasks}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dummy}
\columnbreak
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task Equations
\task[] $P=(0,2)$
\task![] $a:\, y=x$
\task![] $b:\, y=x+2$
\task![] $c:\, y=-x+2$
\end{tasks}
\end{multicols}

\newpage

%one tasks inside multicols
%Doesn't work, taskes piled at the top instead of aligning with their corresponding image. Also, numbers should go on the left.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dummy}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dummy}
\columnbreak
\begin{tasks}[resume=false](2)
\task Equations
\task[] $P=(0,2)$
\task![] $a:\, y=x$
\task![] $b:\, y=x+2$
\task![] $c:\, y=-x+2$
\end{tasks}
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task Equations
\task[] $P=(0,2)$
\task![] $a:\, y=x$
\task![] $b:\, y=x+2$
\task![] $c:\, y=-x+2$
\end{tasks}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

How can I get my intended result?

Answer (score 2):

Using `tasks` when you don't want the list to be numbered horizontally is not really the best option, but anyway. Starting from your first example:

- Use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and then add `valign=t` to the `\includegraphics` options in order to get the enumeration label aligned with the top-left corner of the figure. Note that `adjustbox` already loads `graphicx`.
- For the second column use just one `\task` command and align the equations in other easier way, e.g. with the `aligned` environment (requires the `amsmath` package)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](4)
\task*(2) \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}

\task[] $\begin{aligned}[t]
&{\rm Equations}\\
& a:\, y=x\\
&b:\, y=x+2\\
&c:\, y=-x+2
\end{aligned}$

\task[] $P=(0,2)$

\task*(2) \ldots \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I said, using `tasks` for this is overkilling. With an `enumerate` environment and some `\hfill` to ensure equal spacing between columns would suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-a}
\hfill
$\begin{aligned}[t]
&{\rm Equations}\\
& a:\, y=x\\
&b:\, y=x+2\\
&c:\, y=-x+2
\end{aligned}$
\hfill
$P=(0,2)$
\hfill

\item \ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]